# Is there a way to fade out the Explorer Panel?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I like having the explorer panel open while I'm coding, but it draws too much attention to itself visually. I'd love if the entire panel would fade out (reduce the opacity) when my mouse is off the panel, but fade back in when my mouse moves over the panel.

[image: Here's a picture of what it would look like faded out.]

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not quite what you are looking for, but there are icon themes that allow you to set the saturation and opacity of icons. For example, [Material Icon Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PKief.material-icon-theme). My explorer view uses only greyscale for precisely the reason you mentioned.